# How can I limit 'insert into' based on a foreign key value?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have two tables;

**tbl_ride**

```
+---------+--------------+----------+
| rideID  |   rideName   | duration |
+---------+--------------+----------+
|   1     |    NY Tour   |     3    |
|   2     | Night Life   |     2    |
+---------+--------------+----------+
```

**tbl_day**

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| dayID      |   rideID  | routeMap |
+---------+--------------+----------+
|   1        |     1     |   A-B    |
|   2        |     1     |   B-C    |
|   3        |     1     |   C-D    |
|   4        |     2     |   A-B    |
|   5        |     2     |   B-C    |
+---------+--------------+----------+
```

So I need to be able to limit the number of records being recorded into `tbl_day` based on the `tbl_ride.duration`. Can this be achieved through SQL or should this be achieved through the code? I would appreciate the help either way.

Following is my current MySQL code for JDBC:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_tour_day` (`tourID`, `startHotel`, `endHotel`, `routeNote`, `routeMap`) 
VALUES ( (SELECT tourID from tbl_tour_ride where tbl_tour_ride.tourID = ?), ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: So you can only have 8 ride_id =  1 per day?

Comment: If `tbl_ride.duration` amount of records for some `rideID` is reached does the next record for this `rideID` must be: 1) ignored 2) ejected with error 3) inserted instead of some existing (the most ancient?) record 4) something else. And show FULL `tbl_day`'s DDL.

Comment: @Akina If the ` tbl_ride.duration value` is 2 for some `rideID` then the user should be able to only add 2 records for the foreign key `rideID` in `tbl_day`. If the maximum for the `tbl_day` for a specific `rideID` is reached then an error should inform that "All days for this ride has been specified"

Comment: @P.Salmon Your question was not clear. Can u elaborate?

Comment: This may be easily implemented using BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: There are 24 hours in a day and ride 1 is 3 hours duration - so you can get 8 ride1s in a day? Or is duration not in hours?

Comment: @P.Salmon duration as in number of days

Comment: Ah. So if it's a 3 day duration and days1-3 are already booked you cannot double book on any of these days.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes exactly!

Comment: I don't think your model makes sense - certainly not to me.

Comment: @P.Salmon actually [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933233/how-can-i-submit-the-data-from-dynamic-table-into-database-java  This is the scenario I am looking for. The assumption is that a tour rides are being scheduled and during a one event there are multiple days where each day consists of a route to be followed with a starting hotel and an ending hotel. That is the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_tbl_day
BEFORE INSERT 
ON tbl_day
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF    COALESCE(( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_day WHERE rideID = NEW.rideID ), 0)
   >=
      COALESCE(( SELECT MAX(duration) FROM tbl_ride WHERE rideID = NEW.rideID ), 0) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE = '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'All days for this ride has been specified';
END IF;
END
```

If no record in `tbl_ride` for new `rideID` then insertion not allowed (the amount assumed to be zero).

If there are more than one record in `tbl_ride` for new `rideID` then the maximal value is used as a limit.

Comment: That makes sense and it worked!. Thank you. By the way, i am very new with triggers. Where will i see the error message that u have defined? Is it possible to retrieve that error message within java?

Comment: *Where will i see the error message that u have defined?* This is common error message. Where you can see the error message about syntax error, foreign key violation, incorrect datatype, etc.? any error occured during query execution. This custom message may be retrieved by the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of a valid query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_tour_day 
(tourID
,startHotel
,endHotel
,routeNote
,routeMap
)  
SELECT tourID 
     , ?
     , ?
     , ?
     , ?
  from tbl_tour_ride 
 where tbl_tour_ride.tourID = ?
```

Comment: This does not answer the question made by OP.