# How can I submit the data from dynamic table into database?

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, jdbc

Currently I have a dynamic table inside the form using the following HTML and Javascript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRows(){ 
 var table = document.getElementById('tourdaytbl');
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var cellCount = table.rows[0].cells.length; 
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 for(var i =0; i <= cellCount; i++){
  var cell = 'cell'+i;
  cell = row.insertCell(i);
  var copycel = document.getElementById('col'+i).innerHTML;
  cell.innerHTML=copycel;
  
 }
}
function deleteRows(){
 var table = document.getElementById('tourdaytbl');
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 if(rowCount > '2'){
  var row = table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);
  rowCount--;
 }
 else{
  alert('There should be atleast one row');
 }
}
</script>
```

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8080/project/sampleapi/tourday" method="post">    
 <table id="tourdaytbl">
  <tr>
   <th hidden>tourID</th>
   <th>startHotel</th>
   <th>endHotel</th>
   <th>routeNote</th> 
   <th>routeMap</th> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td id="col0" hidden><input type="text" name="tourID" value="<%=request.getParameter("tourID")%>"/></td> 
   <td id="col1"><input type="text" name="startHotel" /></td> 
   <td id="col2"><input type="text" name="endHotel"  /></td>
   <td id="col3"><input type="text" name="routeNote" /></td>
   <td id="col4"><input type="text" name="endHotel" /></td> 
   
  </tr>  
 </table> 
 <table> 
  <tr> 
   <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRows()" /></td> 
   <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRows()" /></td> 
   <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td> 
  </tr>  
 </table> 
 </form>
```

The following is the post method code:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addTourDay(     @FormParam("tourID") int tourID,
                            @FormParam("startHotel") String startHotel,
                            @FormParam("endHotel") String endHotel,
                            @FormParam("routeNote") String routeNote,
                            @FormParam("routeNote") String routeMap) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    TourDay tourDay = new TourDay();

    tourDay.setTourID(tourID);
    tourDay.setStartHotel(startHotel);
    tourDay.setEndHotel(endHotel);
    tourDay.setRouteNote(routeNote);
    tourDay.setRouteMap(routeMap);

    TourDayDao.getInstance().add(tourDay);

    logger.info("Tour and Ride-Out was submitted to the database successfully!");

}
```

And the database dao:

```
public boolean add(TourDay tourDay) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    if(tourDay != null) {

        Connection connection = Configs.getDbConnection();
        String sql =    "INSERT INTO `tbl_tour_day` (`tourID`, `startHotel`, `endHotel`, `routeNote`, `routeMap`)" + 
                "VALUES ( (SELECT tourID from tbl_tour_ride where tbl_tour_ride.tourID = ?), ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setInt(1, tourDay.getTourID());
        stmt.setString(2, tourDay.getStartHotel());
        stmt.setString(3, tourDay.getEndHotel());
        stmt.setString(4, tourDay.getRouteNote());
        stmt.setString(5, tourDay.getRouteMap());

        int count = stmt.executeUpdate();

        if(count > 0) {
            System.out.println("Successfully Added");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I click on the Submit button only the first row is being stored in the database. The rest of the dynamic rows are not being stored. How can I fix this issue?